# how to call XML based web service through a blackberry eclipse JDE

Tags: xml, networking, blackberry

I want to know how to call an XML based web service from blackberry eclipse.
Is there any code or any other libraries I should use? I am using ksoap libraries.

But I'm still unable to make a contact with server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is within your web server, so to narrow down whether it's the client or the server which is having problem this is you should do :
In the client :
Do a get to a working web page in the internet and show the page HTML content in a richtextfield in your BB device/simulator.

If it's working than check also in ther server

In the server :
- Create a test page which uses form that submit your request to the server and see if it's received by the server and give the proper respond.

Basically it's just the same as requesting any web page.
There are so many example out there, for start try in Blackberry developer section web page.